# How do I play one animation on legs and another on the torso when importing animations with Maximo

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

There are two animations in FBX.
The first is digging. The second is running.
Both animations are taken from Maximo.
Tell me how you can take the digging animation and overlay it on the running animation so that as a result the arms and torso dig while the lower half of the body runs.

[image]